# Memory corruption embedding python with OpenCV in a C++ already using OpenCV but different version

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm trying to embed python code in a C++ application. Problem is that if I use OpenCV functions in the C++ code and also in python function I am embedding there is memory corruption. Simply commenting all the opencv functions from the code below solve the problem.
One thing is that my OpenCV for c++ is 4.5.0 (dinamically linked), compiled from source while version used in python is 3.1.0 (installed using the python wheel).

Looking at the backtrace (but I am not an expert on this) seems to me that resize function in python is somehow relying on the OpenCV 4.5.0 library to free memory, causing some sort of conflicts between the two version..
Python is version 3.5.2.

This is a minimal example.

My main cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    cv::Mat test = cv::imread("/home/rocco/repo/cpp_python/current.jpg");
    cv::Mat test_res;
    cv::resize(test,test_res,cv::Size(),0.5,0.5);
    cv::imwrite("resized.jpg",test_res);
    std::string path = "/home/rocco/repo/cpp_python/current.jpg";
    std::string filename = "script";
    std::string function_name = "myfunction";

    std::string wkd = "/home/rocco/repo/cpp_python";

    auto script_name = PyUnicode_FromString(filename.c_str());
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject *sys_path = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyList_Insert(sys_path, 0, PyUnicode_FromString(wkd.c_str()));
    PySys_SetObject("path", sys_path);
    PyObject *pModule;
    pModule = PyImport_Import(script_name);

    auto pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, function_name.c_str());

    PyObject * pValue = NULL, * pArgs = NULL;
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
    auto pFilename = PyUnicode_FromString(path.c_str());

    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pFilename);  

    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

    Py_DECREF(pArgs);

    Py_DECREF(pFunc);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pFilename);


    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

My python script:

```
import cv2
 
def myfunction(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    scale_percent = 0.5 # percent of original size
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=scale_percent, fy=scale_percent)
    cv2.imwrite('resized2.jpg',img)


myfunction('current.jpg')
```

Backtrace provided here:

```
*** Error in `/home/rocco/repo/cpp_python/cpp_python': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000002447670 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777f5)[0x7f1a8c9807f5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8038a)[0x7f1a8c98938a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f1a8c98d58c]
/home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x103b8c)[0x7f1a8639bb8c]
/home/rocco/dynamic_libraries/opencv_4-5/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.5(_ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv+0x100)[0x7f1a8d5aa140]
/home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x114fe8)[0x7f1a863acfe8]
/home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x1154d4)[0x7f1a863ad4d4]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyCFunction_Call+0xe9)[0x7f1a90686049]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x7555)[0x7f1a90792135]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x79d9)[0x7f1a907925b9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(+0x24ac6c)[0x7f1a90822c6c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x23)[0x7f1a90822d43]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1b)[0x7f1a9078a94b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(+0x1bf5fd)[0x7f1a907975fd]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyCFunction_Call+0xc9)[0x7f1a90686029]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x8c0e)[0x7f1a907937ee]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(+0x24ac6c)[0x7f1a90822c6c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x62d9)[0x7f1a90790eb9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x79d9)[0x7f1a907925b9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x79d9)[0x7f1a907925b9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x79d9)[0x7f1a907925b9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(+0x24ac6c)[0x7f1a90822c6c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x23)[0x7f1a90822d43]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(+0xd2ac8)[0x7f1a906aaac8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x6e)[0x7f1a9075f46e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(_PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs+0x1bf)[0x7f1a9073d95f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject+0x864)[0x7f1a907c98d4]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(+0x1be638)[0x7f1a90796638]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyCFunction_Call+0xe9)[0x7f1a90686049]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x6e)[0x7f1a9075f46e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyObject_CallFunction+0xcf)[0x7f1a9075f5cf]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyImport_Import+0xe6)[0x7f1a907c9d66]
/home/rocco/repo/cpp_python/cpp_python[0x402291]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f1a8c929840]
/home/rocco/repo/cpp_python/cpp_python[0x401e89]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00407000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9180205                            /home/rocco/repo/cpp_python/cpp_python
00606000-00607000 r--p 00006000 08:04 9180205                            /home/rocco/repo/cpp_python/cpp_python
00607000-00608000 rw-p 00007000 08:04 9180205                            /home/rocco/repo/cpp_python/cpp_python
01e0d000-0251f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f1a64000000-7f1a64021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a64021000-7f1a68000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a690f0000-7f1a690f1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a690f1000-7f1a6a74d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a6a74d000-7f1a6beeb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a6beeb000-7f1a6bf7f000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530555                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_generator.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6bf7f000-7f1a6c17f000 ---p 00094000 08:04 530555                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_generator.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c17f000-7f1a6c1a3000 rw-p 00094000 08:04 530555                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_generator.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c1a3000-7f1a6c1a5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a6c1a5000-7f1a6c1b0000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530563                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_sfc64.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c1b0000-7f1a6c3af000 ---p 0000b000 08:04 530563                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_sfc64.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c3af000-7f1a6c3b1000 rw-p 0000a000 08:04 530563                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_sfc64.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c3b1000-7f1a6c3bf000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530561                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_pcg64.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c3bf000-7f1a6c5bf000 ---p 0000e000 08:04 530561                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_pcg64.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c5bf000-7f1a6c5c1000 rw-p 0000e000 08:04 530561                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_pcg64.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c5c1000-7f1a6c5d2000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530566                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_philox.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c5d2000-7f1a6c7d1000 ---p 00011000 08:04 530566                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_philox.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c7d1000-7f1a6c7d3000 rw-p 00010000 08:04 530566                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_philox.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c7d3000-7f1a6c7d4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a6c7d4000-7f1a6c7eb000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530559                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_mt19937.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c7eb000-7f1a6c9eb000 ---p 00017000 08:04 530559                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_mt19937.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c9eb000-7f1a6c9ed000 rw-p 00017000 08:04 530559                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_mt19937.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6c9ed000-7f1a6ca3b000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530556                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_bounded_integers.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6ca3b000-7f1a6cc3b000 ---p 0004e000 08:04 530556                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_bounded_integers.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6cc3b000-7f1a6cc3d000 rw-p 0004e000 08:04 530556                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_bounded_integers.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6cc3d000-7f1a6ce58000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9437776                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f1a6ce58000-7f1a6d057000 ---p 0021b000 08:04 9437776                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f1a6d057000-7f1a6d073000 r--p 0021a000 08:04 9437776                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f1a6d073000-7f1a6d07f000 rw-p 00236000 08:04 9437776                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f1a6d07f000-7f1a6d082000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a6d082000-7f1a6d088000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 7086087                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d088000-7f1a6d287000 ---p 00006000 08:04 7086087                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d287000-7f1a6d288000 r--p 00005000 08:04 7086087                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d288000-7f1a6d289000 rw-p 00006000 08:04 7086087                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d289000-7f1a6d2b9000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530568                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_common.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d2b9000-7f1a6d4b8000 ---p 00030000 08:04 530568                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_common.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d4b8000-7f1a6d4ba000 rw-p 0002f000 08:04 530568                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_common.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d4ba000-7f1a6d4bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a6d4bb000-7f1a6d4e0000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530557                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_bit_generator.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d4e0000-7f1a6d6e0000 ---p 00025000 08:04 530557                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_bit_generator.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d6e0000-7f1a6d6e5000 rw-p 00025000 08:04 530557                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_bit_generator.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d6e5000-7f1a6d6e6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a6d6e6000-7f1a6d75e000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530558                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d75e000-7f1a6d95d000 ---p 00078000 08:04 530558                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d95d000-7f1a6d983000 rw-p 00077000 08:04 530558                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d983000-7f1a6d985000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a6d985000-7f1a6d99b000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 529217                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/fft/_pocketfft_internal.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6d99b000-7f1a6db9a000 ---p 00016000 08:04 529217                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/fft/_pocketfft_internal.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6db9a000-7f1a6db9b000 rw-p 00015000 08:04 529217                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/fft/_pocketfft_internal.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6db9b000-7f1a6dbd2000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 6824744                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpdec.so.2.4.2
7f1a6dbd2000-7f1a6ddd1000 ---p 00037000 08:04 6824744                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpdec.so.2.4.2
7f1a6ddd1000-7f1a6ddd2000 r--p 00036000 08:04 6824744                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpdec.so.2.4.2
7f1a6ddd2000-7f1a6ddd3000 rw-p 00037000 08:04 6824744                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpdec.so.2.4.2
7f1a6ddd3000-7f1a6ddf7000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 7150229                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6ddf7000-7f1a6dff6000 ---p 00024000 08:04 7150229                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6dff6000-7f1a6dff7000 r--p 00023000 08:04 7150229                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6dff7000-7f1a6e000000 rw-p 00024000 08:04 7150229                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a6e000000-7f1a70000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a70000000-7f1a70021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a70021000-7f1a74000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a74000000-7f1a78000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a78000000-7f1a78021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a78021000-7f1a7c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a7c010000-7f1a7c190000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a7c190000-7f1a7c197000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 7136401                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7c197000-7f1a7c396000 ---p 00007000 08:04 7136401                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7c396000-7f1a7c397000 r--p 00006000 08:04 7136401                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7c397000-7f1a7c399000 rw-p 00007000 08:04 7136401                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7c399000-7f1a7c3a8000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9437491                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f1a7c3a8000-7f1a7c5a7000 ---p 0000f000 08:04 9437491                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f1a7c5a7000-7f1a7c5a8000 r--p 0000e000 08:04 9437491                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f1a7c5a8000-7f1a7c5a9000 rw-p 0000f000 08:04 9437491                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f1a7c5a9000-7f1a7c5ad000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 7136410                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7c5ad000-7f1a7c7ac000 ---p 00004000 08:04 7136410                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7c7ac000-7f1a7c7ad000 r--p 00003000 08:04 7136410                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7c7ad000-7f1a7c7ae000 rw-p 00004000 08:04 7136410                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7c7ae000-7f1a7c8ae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a7c8ae000-7f1a7c8d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530149                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7c8d9000-7f1a7cad9000 ---p 0002b000 08:04 530149                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cad9000-7f1a7cadb000 rw-p 0002b000 08:04 530149                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cadb000-7f1a7cade000 rw-p 000d4000 08:04 530149                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cade000-7f1a7cae2000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530150                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cae2000-7f1a7cce2000 ---p 00004000 08:04 530150                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cce2000-7f1a7cce3000 rw-p 00004000 08:04 530150                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cce3000-7f1a7cce5000 rw-p 00019000 08:04 530150                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cce5000-7f1a7cda5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a7cda5000-7f1a7cdc7000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 7136407                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cdc7000-7f1a7cfc6000 ---p 00022000 08:04 7136407                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cfc6000-7f1a7cfc7000 r--p 00021000 08:04 7136407                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cfc7000-7f1a7cfcb000 rw-p 00022000 08:04 7136407                    /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cfcb000-7f1a7cfcc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a7cfcc000-7f1a7cfeb000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530237                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_tests.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7cfeb000-7f1a7d1eb000 ---p 0001f000 08:04 530237                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_tests.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7d1eb000-7f1a7d1ed000 rw-p 0001f000 08:04 530237                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_tests.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a7d1ed000-7f1a7d26d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a7d26d000-7f1a7d26e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a7d26e000-7f1a7da6e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a7da6e000-7f1a7f564000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 532531                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-34a18dc3.3.7.so
7f1a7f564000-7f1a7f763000 ---p 01af6000 08:04 532531                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-34a18dc3.3.7.so
7f1a7f763000-7f1a7f77c000 rw-p 01af5000 08:04 532531                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-34a18dc3.3.7.so
7f1a7f77c000-7f1a7f787000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a7f787000-7f1a7f7ff000 rw-p 01be1000 08:04 532531                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-34a18dc3.3.7.so
7f1a7f7ff000-7f1a7f800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a7f800000-7f1a80000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a80000000-7f1a80021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a80021000-7f1a84000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a8401d000-7f1a840dd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a840fe000-7f1a841be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a841be000-7f1a841bf000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a841bf000-7f1a849bf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a849bf000-7f1a849c0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a849c0000-7f1a851c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a851c0000-7f1a852b0000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 532291                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy.libs/libgfortran-ed201abd.so.3.0.0
7f1a852b0000-7f1a854af000 ---p 000f0000 08:04 532291                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy.libs/libgfortran-ed201abd.so.3.0.0
7f1a854af000-7f1a854b1000 rw-p 000ef000 08:04 532291                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy.libs/libgfortran-ed201abd.so.3.0.0
7f1a854b1000-7f1a854b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a854b2000-7f1a854ba000 rw-p 000f2000 08:04 532291                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy.libs/libgfortran-ed201abd.so.3.0.0
7f1a854ba000-7f1a8585f000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 530243                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a8585f000-7f1a85a5e000 ---p 003a5000 08:04 530243                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a85a5e000-7f1a85a7d000 rw-p 003a4000 08:04 530243                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a85a7d000-7f1a85a9e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a85a9e000-7f1a85aa5000 rw-p 01474000 08:04 530243                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a85aa5000-7f1a85ae5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a85ae5000-7f1a85b53000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9441868                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f1a85b53000-7f1a85d53000 ---p 0006e000 08:04 9441868                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f1a85d53000-7f1a85d54000 r--p 0006e000 08:04 9441868                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f1a85d54000-7f1a85d55000 rw-p 0006f000 08:04 9441868                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f1a85d55000-7f1a85e64000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9437261                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7f1a85e64000-7f1a86063000 ---p 0010f000 08:04 9437261                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7f1a86063000-7f1a86064000 r--p 0010e000 08:04 9437261                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7f1a86064000-7f1a86065000 rw-p 0010f000 08:04 9437261                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7f1a86065000-7f1a86066000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a86066000-7f1a86067000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 6819030                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7f1a86067000-7f1a86266000 ---p 00001000 08:04 6819030                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7f1a86266000-7f1a86267000 r--p 00000000 08:04 6819030                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7f1a86267000-7f1a86268000 rw-p 00001000 08:04 6819030                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7f1a86298000-7f1a870f2000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 528776                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a870f2000-7f1a872f1000 ---p 00e5a000 08:04 528776                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a872f1000-7f1a8733f000 rw-p 00e59000 08:04 528776                     /home/rocco/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f1a8733f000-7f1a87465000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a87465000-7f1a8773f000 r--p 00000000 08:04 6816127                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f1a8773f000-7f1a87740000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a87740000-7f1a87f40000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a87f40000-7f1a87f41000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a87f41000-7f1a8a336000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1a8a336000-7f1a8a33b000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 6823807                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread-2_2.so.12.0.0
7f1a8a33b000-7f1a8a53b000 ---p 00005000 08:04 6823807                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread-2_2.so.12.0.0
```

**EDIT**

After some test, I tried updating python to version 3.6.13 but problem persist, in addition I realized that the problem is not related to cv2.resize function but to opencv in general, whatever opencv function I call from python, it calls my dynamic linked opencv 4.5 libray for deallocation, causing the problem.

**EDIT**

Using OpenCV statically linked in C++ everything works as expected.. is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a linking problem.

Python uses "dlopen" to dynamically load libraries, try changing the [flags](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/dlopen.3.en.html) that are passed to this function. For example, using RTLD_DEEPBIND you can specify to prefer the symbols contained by the loaded objects (instead of the global ones with the same name).

Using these two lines:

```py
import os
print(os.RTLD_DEEPBIND | os.RTLD_NOW)
```

You can obtain the int code for these flags, which is 10.

Then you can change the flags used by dlopen by calling `sys.setdlopenflags(10)`:

```cpp
void setFlags()
{
    auto flag = PyLong_FromLong(10);
    auto setdl = PySys_GetObject("setdlopenflags");

    auto arg = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(arg, 0, flag);
    PyObject_CallObject(setdl, arg);
}
```

It must be used before `PyImport_Import`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that python uses binding for c++ functions, and as you mention you are using different opencv versions for opencv c++ and python. Refer to https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d49/tuy_bindings_basics.html for more information about python bindings. One solution will be to use already bonded functions or use the same compiled library version if you create your own bindings.

Comment: The fact is that opencv wheel already contains statically all the libraries and should  not look for eternal libs.. Commenting opencv instructions from cpp, python script works as expected (I guess opencv libraries 4.5 path is not put in LD_LIBRARY_PATH hence python wheel uses internal libraries..

Comment: Yes, I think is like you say, is using internal library. So you have mixed libraries. If you are using Linux you can use command "ldd your_program_name" to check the libraries used, maybe there you can confirm is using different libraries.